# If $f$ is continuous and $g$ is of bounded variation then $f$ is integrable with respect to $g$.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $g$ is of bounded variation on $[a,b]$.

Prove that $f$ is integrable with respect to $g$ on $[a,b]$.

How can I prove this?

Comment: This is the [Riemann Stieltjes integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).

Answer (score 1):

You can prove this in the easier case when $g$ is monotone on $[a,b]$, and then use that $g=V-(V-g)$ is a difference of monotone functions, where $V$ is the total variation of $g$ over $[a,x]$, i.e $V_g(a,x)$. You'll have to use that $f$ is uniformly continuous, and that $g$ has variation bounded by $g(b)-g(a)$. Then, choose a partition  with mesh $<\delta$ such that for each $|x-y|<\delta$, we have $$\tag 1 |f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{\epsilon}{A}$$ where $A=2(g(b)-g(a))$.

You'll have to use that being Riemann Steiltjes integrable is equivalent to the Riemann condition (for monotone integrators), that is, that given $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$  such that $P\supset P_\epsilon$ implies $$U(P,f,\alpha)-L(P,f,\alpha)<\epsilon$$

To this end, you'll have to sue that, because of $(1)$, $$M_k-m_k\leq \epsilon/A$$

where $M_k,m_k$ are the supremum and infimum of $f$ over the $k$th interval. Good luck.

Comment: @ppar What do you call Cauchy's Criterion?

Comment: And what book's hint is it?

Comment: @pparr I ask again, what do you call *Cauchy's Criterion*?

Comment: @pparr Well, that is similar to what I'm calling the "Riemann condition", that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$ such that for any partition finer than $P_\epsilon$, i.e., $P\supset P_\epsilon$, we have $U(P,f,g)-L(P,f,g)<\epsilon$, where $U,L$ are the upper and lower Darboux sums or $f$ w.r.t. $g$. Note that for any monotone integrator, $L(P,f,g)<S(P,f,g)<U(P,f,g)$ where $S$ is the RS sum. In your case, what I think you want is that there exists a parition $P_\epsilon$ such that for any pair $P,Q$ finer than  $P_\epsilon$, your inequality between RS sums hold.

Comment: RS: Riemann Stieltjes (I had to cut off some characters to make it fit in one comment)